# Selenium automation: Nomethoderror undefined method 'my method' for nil:nilclass

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, rspec, ui-automation

**Background:** I'm an automation noob and I'm trying to get some tests up and running using ruby and selenium. I have some understanding of what I'm doing, but I'm still really green.

**Problem:** I'm getting a "nomethoderror undefined method for nil:nilclass" when trying to call a method on an object that should have inherited that method from a page section.

**Troubleshooting and Research:** I searched for similar questions for the nil:nilclass problem and couldn't find anything that really corresponded to what I was trying to do (or it didn't appear that way to my noob eyes). I suspect that I haven't properly instantiated the page section from which I'm trying to call the method, but I'm not sure how to express this to get things to move forward.

**Other Stuff:** I know that there are other libraries which could help me do elements and sections better (like siteprism, etc.), but I'm trying to do this with just selenium and RSpec as an exercise in my training.

Here's the code for the page section

```
require_relative 'abstract_page'

class PageTitleSection < AbstractPage

   def findPageTitle
        @driver.find_element(:class, 'subheader')
   end

 end
```

Here's the code for the Page

```
require_relative 'abstract_page'
require_relative 'page_title_section'


class TagsPage < AbstractPage
  attr_reader :page_title_section
  @page_title_section

  def self.navigateToTags(driver)
    driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/tags')
    return TagsPage.new(driver)
    @page_title_section = PageTitleSection.new(driver)
  end
end
```

Here's the test:
    require 'rspec'
    require 'selenium-webdriver'

```
require_relative 'spec_helper.rb'
require_relative '../pages/tags_page'
require_relative '../pages/page_title_section'

describe 'Basic navigation and confirmation that page title is visible' do

   it 'should navigate to the tags page and find the title' do
     tags_page = TagsPage.navigateToTags(@driver)
     expect(tags_page.page_title_section.findPageTitle).to eq('Tags')
   end
end
```

I'm getting the error on the expect line of the test on the findPageTitle method.

I feel pretty dumb, but I'm hoping someone might be able to point me in the right direction.

Comment: you didn't say specifically what NoMethodError you are getting (what line of code does it originate from) but I noticed the third line of `TagsPage#navigateToTags` is unreachable because you unconditionally return on line 2. I think that is the issue - since the `@page_title_section` never gets set then in your test `tags_page.page_title_section` will be nil

Comment: Hey sorry, I got the NoMethodError on findPageTitle in the expect() part of the test

Answer (score 0):

`tags_page.page_title_section` is nil.
Notice that at navigateToTags method, it is indeed never assigned . The `return` is above it.

```
def self.navigateToTags(driver)
  driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/tags')
  return TagsPage.new(driver)
  @page_title_section = PageTitleSection.new(driver) # <- unreachable code
end
```